# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am following instructions from a number of threads on askubuntu but to no avail. Here they are for your reference:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've burned the iso image to a DVD correctly. A previous thread established that this 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd is the correct md5 checksum for ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Upon restart and attempting to boot from the DVD I get the purple screen shown in the above thread. I have tried booting with combinations of nomodeset, noacpi and noapic. I've turned off secure boot and any Intel SRT technology related options, attempted booting as a legacy and UEFI system.

Attempting to use any of the boot parameters (nomodeset etc) creates weird graphical results on my monitor. It looks like there are 6 small copies of the purple Ubuntu screen at the top of my monitor and a mess of graphical data below it.

Windows 7 is currently installed via a legacy installation process (i.e. verified since no EFI partition exists).

Hardware details:

Graphics Card: Gigabyte AMD Radeon R9 290/REV 1.0 4096MB GDDR5/512 bit/PCI E 3.0

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA - Z97X - UD5H. Intel Z97 - Socket 1150. Rev1.04 DDR3 2-CH/PCI Ex 16/ATX 7.1 CH-HD Audio

CPU: Intel i5 4690K LGA1150 3.5 GHz 6 MB Cache

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: how long did you wait for the screen to exit? It usually lasts about 3 or 4 minutes on even a very fast computer

Comment: Gave it about 5-10 minutes. Still wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: I'll check into it when I get back from vacation